# How can I get sum of a group cell with expression which aggregates the value from other group cells in SSRS? (to get weighted average)

Tags: reporting-services, aggregate, grouping, ssrs-2008, weighted-average

[I have a dataset like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4WCT.png)
[This is how my SSRS Tablix and cell expression look like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0U3P.png)
[I would like to calculate weighted average between "Count" and "Price"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JaRD.png)
Is there any better way that manages to get weighted average between "Count" and "Price" for my Tablix in SSRS?

I multiply "Count" and "Price" through expression as the part with red font (i.e. 1387+3234) and expect to add up the part with red font to the cell highlighted as gray. Sadly, I have no idea how to add up the part with red font to the cell highlighted as gray. Any good suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Did you want the total of the Blue and Red sections or the Weighted Average?

For the total, you should be able to multiply the fields for each row and SUM them.

```
=SUM(Fields!COUNT.Value * Fields!PRICE.Value)
```

For a weighted average, I believe you could SUM up the total value from each row and then divide by the overall COUNT.

```
=SUM(Fields!COUNT.Value * Fields!PRICE.Value) / SUM(Fields!COUNT.Value)
```